# Postman POST request works but doesnt when exported to cURL / request / http.request

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, postman, http.client

I am completly lost because I got no idea anymore what I am doing wrong.

I want to make a simple POST request to a certain address. I visited the website using firefox, opened it's terminal, copied the POST request as cURL and executed in the terminal. The recieved response has status 200 but it's body is unreadable like "������q9i".

But when I use Postman->Import->cURL and execute the request it works?! Also status 200 but this time the body contains a properly readable html code just as expected.
So I though maybe it's because Postman is adjusted the request. So I opened the code panel to the right side of the program and exported Postman's request again as cURL, python - http.client and python - request, but none of them are working?! Again I just recieve an unreadable body. How on earth can this happen?

I'm using the same machine for all requests, there is no VPN or something so it cannot be related to IP address. There is no authentification or anything.

There is just maybe one hint I noticed: The response recieved in Postman is exactly one byte shorter then the one recieved in cURL or python. Could this be the problem? Is Postman handling the response's body differently?

I appreciate any help a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cURL is displaying the raw response of the body, while Postman and Firefox process the response. In your case, I suspect that you request a zipped response with a header like `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`. If you remove that header, you will get the uncompressed response.

If there is no such header in your request, it would be good to see the request you are trying to execute.

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the solution :) I removed the header "Accept-Encoding" and everything works fine!